# ERROR: Failed to decode JSON object en FLASK 2.0.2 con request.json y Postman

Tags: python, json, post, flask

Estoy usando Postman para hacer una POST request a mi API en FLASK 2.0.2

Los datos de Postman:
[Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DUXg.png)
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUfvQ.png)

El código que intento ejecutar es:

```py
app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
app.wsgi_app = GlobalAuth(app.wsgi_app)
configure_logging(app)

api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        request.on_json_loading_failed(e="a")
        data = request.json
        return make_response(data,200)

api.add_resource(Test,'/test')
```

En el middleware (GlobalAuth):

```py
class GlobalAuth:
    pass
    '''
    Simple WSGI middleware
    '''

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        args = request.args
        body_args = request.json
```

El request.json funciona en el middleware pero en el endpoint da el error  `Failed to decode JSON object: error` si añado la siguiente linea antes de request.json: `request.on_json_loading_failed(e="error")`. Si no pongo esa linea simplemente se queda en un bucle infinito y no carga.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no se pudo decodificar (o hasta interpretar) el JSON. Si quitas la línea `request.on_json_loading_failed(e="error")` (que formatea el error), ¿qué te muestra?

Comment: ¿Y si pones `data = request.json` dentro de un bloque `try:`, y luego en un bloque `except Exception as exc:` pones `print(f"{type(exc).__name__}: {str(exc)}"); quit()`? Eso para mostrar directamente el tipo de excepción.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son _todas_ las librería que estás usando? ¿De dónde vienen `Request`, `make_response`, etc.? Esos datos nos pueden dar una pista.